# Tedious - Error: `.connect` can not be called on a Connection in `Final` state

Tags: sql, node.js, tedious

I have this code and it is returning the error : ' Error: `.connect` can not be called on a Connection in `Final` state. '
The thing is, this error is only printed when I make a second request, because the first one returns the correct value.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
const express = require('express')  
const router = express.Router()  
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

const config = require('./config.json');
var connection = new Connection(config);

router.route('/')
    .post(async (req, res) => {
        connection.connect((err) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Connection Failed');
                console.log( err);
            } else {
                executeSQL()
            }
        })

        function executeSQL() {
            let data;
            request = new Request('Here is a select', function(err, rowsCount, rows) {
                if(err) console.log(err)
                else {
                    res.send(rows)
                    // request.fullData = rows;
                }
                connection.close();
            });

            // request.on('requestCompleted', function(rowCountm, more) {
            //     // console.log('dados: ')
            //     console.log(request.fullData)
            // })

            connection.execSql(request);
        }
    });

module.exports = router
```

My DB config:

```
{
    "server": "serverName",
    "authentication": {
        "type": "default",
        "options": {
            "userName": "userName",
            "password": "**"
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "database": "databaseName",
        "rowCollectionOnDone": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
    }
}
```

Comment: This Error happens when you execute a query but the connection is closed.

Comment: Thank you Babak, I could fix this problem with the code I inserted on the anwsers

Answer (score 1):

I did fix this error.

Basically, I need to create a new connection everytime the end point is called.
Here is the code :

```
 const getConnection = async () => {
    if(connection) return connection;
       connection = new Connection(config);
 };

    getConnection()
```